# Infinite loop due to wrong condition in C

Tags: c

Hey guys i'm new to C and i'm trying to learn something by myself.

So here's the question: i have an infinite loop and i don't understand why.
I've already checked other topics but i didn't understand, actually.

Here's the code:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
int main()
{
    int n,i=0; // the number of temperatures to analyse
    scanf("%d", &n); fgetc(stdin);
    char temps[257]; // the n temperatures expressed as integers ranging from -273 to 5526
    fgets(temps, 257, stdin); // the n temperatures expressed as integers ranging from -273 to 5526


    int temp[257]={0};
    char *pointer;

    pointer= temps;


   while(*pointer != NULL){
      int i=0, sign=1;

      if(*pointer == '-'){
          sign=-1;
          pointer++;
      }

     while(*pointer != 32) { //infinite loop!
     if(*pointer >='0' && *pointer<='9'){
         temp[i]= (temp[i] *10) + ((*pointer) -'0');
         temp[i]= temp[i]*sign;
         printf("try");
         }
   }     

      printf("%d\n", temp[i]); //verifying temps != 0
      pointer++;
      i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't understand why.

Anyway, the aim of the program is: "Write a program that prints the temperature closest to 0 among input data. If two numbers are equally close to zero, positive integer has to be considered closest to zero (for instance, if the temperatures are -5 and 5, then display 5)."

You may need it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `while(*pointer != NULL)` would usually give you a compiler warning... most C implementations define `NULL` as `(void *)0`.  Check you aren't using a C++ compiler, and fix it to be `while (*pointer)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the loop:

```
while(*pointer != 32)
```

you never change `pointer` or `*pointer` within the loop body.  So if this loop is entered once then it can never exit.

---

You probably meant to have a `pointer++` somewhere, and perhaps the loop condition should actually be `while(*pointer >='0' && *pointer<='9')` (what if the string has some numbers, then a letter, then some numbers?)

However bear in mind that this loop will also have to check for end-of-string (`'\0'`) and exit the outer loop correctly if it does hit that (instead of doing `pointer++` and going past the terminator as you do in the case of the input being just `-`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually understood. Thank you.

So now this is the loop

```
while(*pointer != 32 || *pointer != '\0') {
         if(*pointer >='0' && *pointer<='9'){
             temp[i]= (temp[i] *10) + ((*pointer) -'0');
             temp[i]= temp[i]*sign;
             pointer++;
         }        
 }
```

Now it gives me values, but at a certain point, it becomes infinite.
The rest of the code is the same.

EDIT: i modified the loop condition with while(*pointer >='0' && *pointer<='9') and it's not infinite! 
But doesn't work. There may be a logical mistake.

EDIT 2: i found it. i've initialized i=0 in the while loop and of course it kept updating the same temp[i].

Thank you again.